# Создание маски изображения в QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

Есть форма, в ней QLabel, в QLabel выводится картинка. Задача в том, что бы мышью выделить объект на картинке и сохранить маску изображения (т.е. например, объект заливается черным цветом, а фон белым). Как это можно реализовать ? Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Comment: С помощью кода!

Comment: С выделением всё просто - QRubberBand. Поиск объектов на изображении - это целое направление в computer science

Comment: Спасибо! Поиск объектов не нужен, пользователь сам с помощью мыши выделяет объект